# Streaming audio on Flutter with websocket not working as expected

Tags: flutter, audio, streaming

So I am opening a websocket connection with elevenlabs api like this and fetching stream of audio data :

```
final socketChannel = IOWebSocketChannel.connect(

        'wss://api.elevenlabs.io/v1/text-to-speech/${widget.voiceId}/stream-input?model_id=$model');

    final AudioPlayer audioPlayer = AudioPlayer();

    final streamController = StreamController<List<int>>();



    final myCustomSource = MyCustomSource(streamController.stream);



    final bosMessage = {

      "text": " ",

      "voice_settings": {"stability": 0.5, "similarity_boost": true},

      "xi_api_key": "api_key",

    };



    socketChannel.sink.add(jsonEncode(bosMessage));

    socketChannel.stream.listen((message) async {

      final response = jsonDecode(message);

      if (response['audio'] != null) {

        try {

          final audioChunk = response['audio'] as String;

          final uint8List = Uint8List.fromList(base64.decode(audioChunk));



          streamController.add(uint8List);

        } catch (e) {

          print("Error setting audio source and playing: $e");

        }

      }

    }, onDone: () async {

      print('we are done here');

      await audioPlayer.setAudioSource(myCustomSource);

      print('source is done');

      try {

        audioPlayer.play();

      } catch (e) {

        print('error is $e');

      }
```

MyCustomSource is set up like this :

```
class MyCustomSource extends StreamAudioSource {

  final Stream<List<int>> byteStream;

  final List<int> bytes = [];

  MyCustomSource(this.byteStream) {

    byteStream.listen((data) {



      bytes.addAll(data);

    });

  }



  @override

  Future<StreamAudioResponse> request([int? start, int? end]) async {

    start ??= 0;

    end ??= bytes.length;

    return StreamAudioResponse(

      sourceLength: bytes.length,

      contentLength: end - start,

      offset: start,

      stream: Stream.value(bytes.sublist(start, end)),

      contentType: 'audio/mpeg',

    );

  }

}
```

Now the issue is audio plays smoothly when I am setting the source and playing the audio inside onDone(){}. But my expected behaviour is that to play audio as the streamed chunks arrive and keep playing it. The issue right now iis that if I amove the .setAudioSource and .play beofre onDone and inside listen, each time a new audio chunk comes in, a new audiosource is set which starts from the beginning and goes as far as the new streamed chunk. So what happens is that anytime a new streamed chunk arrives, it starts playing from the beginning essentially repeating itself before finishing it up.

How can I fix it so that it starts playing immediately and continue playing rather than restarting from the beginning

Comment: How about keep position with audioPlayer.positionStream.listen((position) {       
        print('Current position: $position');
      }); and seek(position) before play

Answer (score 0):

With this change, you create the MyCustomSource and set the initial audio source
before listening to the WebSocket stream. As new audio chunks arrive, you add
them to the streamController, and the MyCustomSource will automatically update
to include these new chunks. The audio will continue to play without restarting
from the beginning as new data arrives from the WebSocket stream.

```
     // Define MyCustomSource outside the widget build method to maintain its state.
final streamController = StreamController<List<int>>();
final myCustomSource = MyCustomSource(streamController.stream);

// Inside your widget's build method or wherever you are creating the WebSocket connection:
final socketChannel = IOWebSocketChannel.connect(
  'wss://api.elevenlabs.io/v1/text-to-speech/${widget.voiceId}/stream-input?model_id=$model',
);
final AudioPlayer audioPlayer = AudioPlayer();

final bosMessage = {
  "text": " ",
  "voice_settings": {"stability": 0.5, "similarity_boost": true},
  "xi_api_key": "api_key",
};

socketChannel.sink.add(jsonEncode(bosMessage));

socketChannel.stream.listen((message) async {
  final response = jsonDecode(message);
  if (response['audio'] != null) {
    try {
      final audioChunk = response['audio'] as String;
      final uint8List = Uint8List.fromList(base64.decode(audioChunk));

      // Add the new audio chunk to the stream
      streamController.add(uint8List);
    } catch (e) {
      print("Error setting audio source and playing: $e");
    }
  }
}, onDone: () {
  print('WebSocket connection closed.');
});

// Set the initial audio source
await audioPlayer.setAudioSource(myCustomSource);

// Start playing the audio
audioPlayer.play();
```

Comment: Hi, but it will still play only after the connection is completed, iits still playing basically onDone rather than as soon as we get first chunk.

Please can you help with this?

Answer (score 0):

the audio player and source are set up before the WebSocket connection is established

```
  final AudioPlayer audioPlayer = AudioPlayer();
    final streamController = StreamController<List<int>>();
    
    final myCustomSource = MyCustomSource(streamController.stream);
    
    final socketChannel = IOWebSocketChannel.connect(
        'wss://api.elevenlabs.io/v1/text-to-speech/${widget.voiceId}/stream-input?model_id=$model');
    
    final bosMessage = {
      "text": " ",
      "voice_settings": {"stability": 0.5, "similarity_boost": true},
      "xi_api_key": "api_key",
    };
    
    socketChannel.sink.add(jsonEncode(bosMessage));
    
    socketChannel.stream.listen((message) async {
      final response = jsonDecode(message);
      if (response['audio'] != null) {
        try {
          final audioChunk = response['audio'] as String;
          final uint8List = Uint8List.fromList(base64.decode(audioChunk));
    
          streamController.add(uint8List);
          
          // If it's the first chunk, start playing immediately.
          if (!audioPlayer.isPlaying) {
            await audioPlayer.setAudioSource(myCustomSource);
            audioPlayer.play();
          }
        } catch (e) {
          print("Error setting audio source and playing: $e");
        }
      }
    }, onDone: () async {
      print('WebSocket connection is done');
      // You can add code here for handling when the WebSocket is closed if needed.
    });
```